# Why is MergeContent is creating replicas in NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am consuming JSON messages from queues using NiFi, these JSONs can have varying lengths and fields. I have added MergeContent to merge messages that came in for 15 minutes into a single flow file.

NiFi is running on 3 nodes.

The MergeContent processor is creating duplicate files, now sure why? Any help will be appreciated, not sure what I am doing wrong.
[image: MergeContent]

Comment: try with setting `Minimum Number of Entries` > 1 (say 10) and `Minimum Group Size` > 0 B (say 5 MB). Have a look at this - https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Apache-Nifi-Merge-Content/td-p/158619

Comment: details about all the properties supported by `MergeContent` - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html

Comment: for your 15 minutes criteria, set `Max Bin Age` property duration

Comment: Is your "consumer" running on all three nodes? That might be the cause of your duplicates rather than the MergeContent Processor.

Comment: Do you mind my asking if you ever solved this?  I'm having similar issues and am curious what your fix was.